# What hadith is this?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, islamic-scholar, sahih-bukhari

T.P Hughes, in his Dictionary on Islam, quotes a hadith from Bukhari which he claims is found on Pg. 1127 line 7.'

"The Imam Muhammad Isma'il al-Bukhari (p. 1127, line 7), records that Ibn `Abbas said that` the word Tahrif (corruption) signifies to change a thing from its original nature; and that there is no man who could corrupt a single word of what proceeded from God, so that the Jews and Christians could corrupt only by misrepresenting the meaning of the words of God.'" (T. P. Hughes, Dictionary of Islam [Kazi Publications, Inc, 3023-27 West Belmont Avenue, Chicago Il. 60618, 1994], p. 62)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a hadith. Al-Bukhari recorded it in his Sahih under one of the chapter headings in the book of Tawhid, but only as a educated opinion on the chapter topic rather than as a hadith from the prophet himself.

Using sunnah.com's numbering scheme, you can find it in book 97, chapter 55, between hadiths #7552 and #7553 ([link](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97#177)), but they don't tend to translate these sorts of inclusions as they are not actually ahadith.

Comment: In fact most of these inclusion are ahadith (in the general meaning) which Al-Bukhari quoted as a support as the chains may not reach the standard of his Sahih, but they are more authentic than many hassan and da'if narration in other hadith compilations. It is out of ignorance that sunnah.com ignores translating them. Many scholars refer to these inclusions.

Comment: @Medi1Saif That may be true in general, but this one in particular doesn't even claim to be the words of the prophet or anything other than Ibn Abbas' personal understanding of the terms. I do agree that sunnah.com is doing a disservice by not translating them though, as they are valuable.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Do you know of the chain of this narration? My impression from reading Ibn Hajar was that it is rather dubious, maybe even most of the statement is actually of Bukhari rather than Ibn Abbas.

Comment: @UmH no not this specific one. I think this could be a good question to investigate.

Comment: @Medi1Saif can you give me a reference to Islamic scholars on the inclusions of ahadith like these.